# Why I can't create a file in the internal directory?

Tags: java, android, file-io

I'm trying to create a new file by:

`File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "test.tmp");`

After that I have the follwing code:

```
try {
      fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

      ..... other not important code
```

And it throws the following error:

`android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

regarding this line:

`fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));`

Isn't `File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "test.tmp");` supposed to create the file?

Can you give me a clue? I know that I'm missing a small but important part here, but I'm unable to spot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "test.tmp"); supposed to create the file?

No. It creates a Java object, an instance of class `File`. It has no impact on the filesystem.

Use `exists()` on the `File` object to see if the file exists. Or, if for some reason you want the empty file there, call `createNewFile()` on the `File` object.

Comment: The problem is that `exists()` returns `true`

Comment: @Slim: I don't see where you are calling `exists()`. I cannot think of a scenario under which `exists()` would return `true`, but you would be unable to read the file, under normal circumstances. One scenario where you could get into trouble if you are messing with `android:sharedUserId` in the manifest, in which case try uninstalling and reinstalling the app.